# How to get only one character back out of a string in C?

Tags: c, string, char

```
int main(void) {
  char x[50];

  fgets( x, 50, stdin );
  printf( "%s", &(x[1]) );
} //  main
```

If I type `Hello World` in this program it will output `ello World` but I just want the letter `e` returned. How can I do that?

Comment: Use `printf( "%c", x[1] );`. Knowledge of data types are necessary in any programming language.

Comment: I recommend reading up about pointers, dereferencing and null-terminated strings.

Comment: The [`printf` man page here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx) is involved and tricky, linking to other man pages too. An hour or three exploring until your head explodes can be better than a night out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options for printing a single character with `printf`:

- Use `%c` format specifier, and pass the character that you want to print (not a pointer to a character), or
- Use `%s` with a limit of one character, i.e. `%.1s`

The first option looks like this:

```
printf( "%c", x[1]);
```

The second option looks like this:

```
printf( "%.1s", &x[1]);
```

Note the dot in front of `1`, which specifies the *upper* limit on the length. Without a dot `.` the number would set the *lower* limit.

Comment: note: there are also a range of options not involving printf, e.g. `putchar(x[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with:

```
printf("%c",x[1]);
```